# nginx dependency problem trying to upgrade

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates, dpkg, nginx

Trying to upgrade my Ubuntu 12.04 vps I get the following error:

```
henrik@neung:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for henrik: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx-full : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.2.4-1ubuntu0ppa2~precise) but 1.2.4-2ubuntu0ppa1~precise is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

So I try to run this:

```
henrik@neung:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  nginx-full
The following packages will be upgraded:
  nginx-full
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 42 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/441 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx-full:
 nginx-full depends on nginx-common (= 1.2.4-1ubuntu0ppa2~precise); however:
  Version of nginx-common on system is 1.2.4-2ubuntu0ppa1~precise.
dpkg: error processing nginx-full (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
 nginx depends on nginx-full | nginx-light; however:
  Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
dpkg: error processing nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-full
 nginx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anybody help fix this?

Comment: Take your time looking [this *general purpose* question](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/62483). If you have no luck with that, try reinstalling the `nginx` package: `sudo apt-get remove nginx* && sudo apt-get install nginx-full`

Comment: I went through the whole thing, but no luck. So I tried removing and installing, and after a reboot everything worked ok. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it as the right solution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that `nginx-full` depends on `nginx-common`, this means that you can't install  the package `nginx-full` without have a **specific version** of `nginx-common`.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/q/140246/62483) is an question dedicated to this problem, but the resolution is very extensive, reaching to, not only one, but different cases. So I will show you a short but effective method.

Actually, I don't know how to install that version of `nginx-common`, but I know that you will solve your problem by **reinstalling all the package**. To do that you must enter the following command in a terminal.

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx* && sudo apt-get install nginx-full
```

Comment: a reboot was required after these steps to make it all work! Thanks

Comment: I needed to stop Apache (also serving on port 80) before this worked.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.
I DO NOT have Apache, and nothing else was blocking my port 80.
I could NOT install nginx with

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

nor with

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-common nginx-full
```

After one week I stumbled over this little blog: https://etc.banana.fish/?p=75

In this blog, the solution is:

1. Install nginx-common: `sudo apt-get install nginx-common`
2. Remove `listen [::]:80 default_server;` from **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default** (I made this using the root-user)
3. Just to be sure, I did reboot my server.
4. Just to be sure twice, I did `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`.
5. Now I finally called `sudo apt-get install nginx-full` and it worked!

Afterwords I could see the Titlescreen of nginx, when I typed in the IP of my remote server!

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong feeling that you forgot to run `sudo apt-get update` prior to running `sudo apt-get upgrade` - the package manager uses old information about `nginx-common` package version while `nginx-full` requires a newer version.

Comment: No, I did that.