# Can't update nginx because of debconf

Tags: 14.04, apt, dpkg, nginx, debconf

I'm on 14.04.5 LTS. I get this error when running a normal apt-get upgrade:

```
Setting up nginx-common (1.10.1-3+trusty1) ...
dpkg: error processing package nginx-common (--configure):  
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

I've omitted all the subsequent errors caused by this, "Package nginx-common is not configured yet.", etc.

I followed the process in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/449022/518847) to debug the `.postinst` and it never gets beyond the 3rd line: `. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule` – that's what's returning the `1`.

I've tried [this solution](https://serverfault.com/a/565291/102407) but it didn't help, debconf is definitely accessible. And [these ones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243568/nginx-dependency-problem-trying-to-upgrade) (the error persists). I have no ipv6 listen directives in any included conf files as far as I can tell.

I have no clue as to how I'd debug debconf to see why it's failing. Does anyone know what I should try next?

---

**Edit:** New updates, they install but I get this error at the end:

```
Setting up nginx-full (1.10.1-3+trusty2) ...
initctl: invalid command: upgrade
Try `initctl --help' for more information.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "upgrade" failed.
```

Not sure if I should mark as resolved.

Comment: that update you did sounds like its own unique individual *different* issue - you should open a new question.  I also have a fix in the works for this (it's a completely different issue, so it should be its own question, but it would be closed as a bug report)

Comment: Note that your second issue is actually in this question, and has multiple open bugs:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209585/nginx-logrotate-error-on-cron-job

Comment: Note that I have fixes uploaded and pending in the staging PPAs currently - the builders are a little overloaded, and I've slammed them fairly hard today so patience is a virtue (I still suggest splitting the second issue off into it's own question because it's entirely unrelated to the original core issue you've reported)

Comment: Thanks @ThomasWard, pretty sure the question you linked is exactly the same as my second issue.

Comment: actually 100% certain it's the issue you're seeing.  Every time the PPAs resync with Debian we lose some distro-specific patches, which includes the patch for this issue.  It's why I never closed the logrotate specific bug referenced in the question I linked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### This specific issue is fixed, please update your packages!

---

#### *Ubuntu Repositories*  ([LP Bug #1637058](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+bug/1637058))

In **Ubuntu Zesty's proposed repository** (this is an in-development release, I hope you aren't using this...), `1.10.1-0ubuntu5` addresses this issue.

In **Ubuntu Trusty, Xenial, and Yakkety,** the Security team has released updated versions of the packages to address this issue, and is considering it a regression in the package.  This information is detailed in the bug and very briefly in the corresponding [Ubuntu Security Notice (USN-3114-2)](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3114-2/), but this issue is fixed in the following versions of the package:

- **Ubuntu Trusty:** `1.4.6-1ubuntu3.7` (Security and Updates repositories)
- **Ubuntu Xenial:** `1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4` (Security and Updates repositories)
- **Ubuntu Yakkety:** `1.10.1-0ubuntu1.2` (Security and Updates repositories)

The version in the **Ubuntu Precise** repositories are not affected, as they were never altered in a way which introduced the CVE which prompted the recent updates. (This only applies to the Ubuntu Repositories, not the PPAs.)

---

#### *PPAs*  ([LP Bug #1637200](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nginx/+bug/1637200))

I have uploaded revised packages to the staging PPA that address this issue, and implement a fix.  These built without issue, and were copied to the primary Mainline and Stable PPAs on Launchpad as of 12:56 PM on October 27, 2016 (UTC-04:00).

This includes fixes for **Precise, Trusty, Xenial, and Yakkety**.  The PPAs do not yet have Zesty support.

---

> **Obligatory disclosure:**
>
> I am the primary person on the Ubuntu Server Team in charge of the `nginx` packages.  I also maintain the PPAs that reside under the team at https://launchpad.net/~nginx.
>
> I also have direct knowledge on this issue, and the process of fixes being made available, because I helped to discover the problem affects the recent Security updates done, and also Debian.

Comment: Benefits of having maintainers who frequent AU. :D

Comment: @muru More so you can blame the eighty or so twitter messages and emails I had this morning when I woke up.  And the bug reports.  And my discovering the problem because I made a mistake applying Debian's patches... which just happened to show the problems here and how to fix it.

Answer (score 7):

#### Official fixed packages have been released, use those

**TL;DR** Scroll to the bottom

Just ran into this issue myself.

To debug it a bit further, I set the following environment variable:

`export DEBCONF_DEBUG=developer`

That way we can see what debconf is doing.

Now we run

`dpkg --configure --pending`

And we can see the following:

```
 Setting up nginx-common (1.10.1-3+xenial1) ...
 debconf (developer): frontend started
 debconf (developer): frontend running, package name is nginx-common
 debconf (developer): starting /var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-common.config configure 1.10.1-3+xenial0
 dpkg: error processing package nginx-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnginx-mod-http-image-filter:
 libnginx-mod-http-image-filter depends on nginx-common (= 1.10.1-3+xenial1); however:
 Package nginx-common is not configured yet.
```

Now we can edit the `/var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-common.config` script, and change

`#!/bin/sh`

with

`#!/bin/sh -x` to enable debugging as well.

Running `dpkg --configure --pending` again will show:

```
Setting up nginx-common (1.10.1-3+xenial1) ...
debconf (developer): frontend started
debconf (developer): frontend running, package name is nginx-common
debconf (developer): starting /var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-common.config configure 1.10.1-3+xenial0
+ set -e
+ . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
+ [ ! 1 ]
+ [ -z  ]
+ exec
+ [  ]
+ exec
+ DEBCONF_REDIR=1
+ export DEBCONF_REDIR
+ logdir=/var/log/nginx
+ log_symlinks_check 1.10.1-3+xenial0
+ [ -z 1.10.1-3+xenial0 ]
+ dpkg --compare-versions 1.10.1-3+xenial0 lt-nl 1.10.1-0ubuntu1.1
+ return
dpkg: error processing package nginx-common (--configure):
```

And now we can see our problematic line in the script

`dpkg --compare-versions 1.10.1-3+xenial0 lt-nl 1.10.1-0ubuntu1.1`

returns exit code 1, as it should -- it's doing a version comparison and returns 0 or 1 depending on the result.

I won't comment on how to properly fix it, as it's an actual bug being tracked at [#1637058 (for Ubuntu)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+bug/1637058) and [#1637200 (for PPAs)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nginx/+bug/1637200) at LP.

**Work-around fix**:

Edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-common.config`

and add a `return` on the first line of the `log_symlinks_check` function.

e.g.:

```
 log_symlinks_check() {
     return                <---- here
     # Skip new installations
     [ -z "$1" ] && return
```

This will allow the upgrade process to continue.

**EDIT** As pointed out by @Thomas Ward, this will skip a setup step (fixing insecure symlinks -- if there are any -- in /var/log/nginx)

Comment: This also prevents the configuration from doing what it should.  I will be poking this today to get fixes out.

Comment: That is correct, but I think there are very few that have logs symlinked in /var/log/nginx -- and if they do, they probably know how to fix this issue without googling it :) Added it to the answer just in case, thanks for the comment!

Comment: Considering that that is the *core issue* of the latest CVE that was patched, skipping is *bad*

Comment: FYI, make a note there are two separate tracking bugs for this - one is for Ubuntu (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+bug/1637058), and one is for the PPAs (https://bugs.launchpad.net/nginx/+bug/1637200)

Comment: Also note that I think we have a fix that will be usable, both for the Ubuntu updates that went out and the PPAs.  Working on testing first.

Answer (score 6):

Having same issue on :

- `14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-32-generic x86_64)`
- `16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-45-generic x86_64)`

> Setting up nginx-common (1.10.1-3+trusty1) ...
>   dpkg: error processing package nginx-common (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam:
>    libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam depends on nginx-common (= 1.10.1-3+trusty1); however:
>     Package nginx-common is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam (--configure):
>    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnginx-mod-http-echo:
>    libnginx-mod-http-echo depends on nginx-common (= 1.10.1-3+trusty1); however:
>     Package nginx-common is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package libnginx-mod-http-echo (--configure):
>    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    nginx-common
>    libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam
>    libnginx-mod-http-echo

#### Solved

I was able to fix the issue by first making a backup of the `/etc/nginx` folder.

```
sudo tar -zcf ~/nginx.tgz /etc/nginx
```

Then I purged anything to do with nginx from the system. I had to do it in step as the dependency issues were triggered.

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx-full
sudo apt-get purge nginx-common
sudo apt-get purge nginx*
```

After that, install nginx back onto the system `sudo apt-get install nginx-full`.

And finally restore the `/etc/nginx` folder with `sudo tar -zxf ~/nginx.tgz` and restart nginx using `sudo service nginx restart`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was trying to avoid `purge` just because I didn't want to lose all the conf, but this seems like a good work-around to that.

Comment: @Walf Yeah it wasn't my first choice either but did the job in the end. Have a look at @Emil Bunzos answer further down for a less `drastic` workaround =].

Comment: Another possible gothcha is if you're using the dynamic loading modules, these will need to be reconfigured to the reinstalled nginx instance. e.g. 
load_module "modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so";

Comment: All workarounds should be considered invalidated now - officially fixed packages have been uploaded to the PPAs and the Repositories.

Comment: Thanks so much this worked great for me. I run a variety of tests of my Nginx Bot Blocker on TravisCI and I test it from 1.10 all the way through to 1.3.x but was having issues getting 1.13.x to start / reload due to this service issue.