# install nginx 1.10.1-3trusty1 got nginx-common installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

Tags: nginx

**UPDATE**

After I removed and purged `nginx` and `nginx-common`, and install it again, it works fine.

---

I install nginx 1.10.1-3+trusty1 got this errors:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/23386350/

I found first error is configure nginx-common, so I modified `/var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-common.postinst` with `set -x`,

then I run this:`sudo dpkg --configure nginx-common`

I got these lines: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23386416/

```
Setting up nginx-common (1.10.1-3+trusty1) ...
+ . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
+ [ !  ]
+ PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1
+ export PERL_DL_NONLAZY
+ [  ]
+ exec /usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-common.postinst configure 1.10.1-3+trusty0
dpkg: error processing package nginx-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-common
```

Comment: Please refer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/842217/cant-update-nginx-because-of-debconf

Comment: @LinusYong thanks, I have added `exit 0;` at the beginning of `nginx-common.postinst` file to solve this issue, it's an ugly workaround.

Comment: @dawncold, the question has a better answer now: http://askubuntu.com/a/842313/25918

Comment: I am marking this as closed as "Only relevant to a specific period of time".  The specific notices in nginx-common that were noted in this question specifically have been resolved, and are obsolete issues no longer prevalent in the latest NGINX versions of the package.  Anyone having this issue should open new individual questions for this.  (FYI: I'm the NGINX package maintainer for the PPA that is being used here as well as the NGINX package in Ubuntu)